# Data from file not being read in linux server C

Tags: c

I have several functions that read from .txt files and populate 2D arrays based on the contained information. The function I'm currently working on is as follows:

```
char** fillCountyList(char inputFile[])
{
    char **countyList = NULL;

    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(inputFile, "r");
    checkFileOpen(input); //a separate function

    countyList = malloc(COUNTIES_IN_SD * sizeof(char*));
    for (int iii = 0; iii < COUNTIES_IN_SD; ++iii)
    {
        countyList[iii] = malloc(COUNTY_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
        fgets(countyList[iii], COUNTY_LENGTH, input);
    }
    return countyList;
}
```

This compiles fine, and when I run it on Visual Studio (15.6.2), it reads the data and creates the array. When I run it on a remote linux server, it doesn't read any data at all.

The file opens fine, but none of the data is read.

I also realize that since both COUNTIES_IN_SD and COUNTY_LENGTH are macros, I could simply create the array statically, but I need to do similar things with other files that I have to use dynamic memory, and this was the simplest example to share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd highly recommend checking for error codes -- check `fopen`'s return, check `fgets`'s return, check all of your `malloc` calls, etc. If any of them return error values (see the corresponding `man` pages), that will likely answer your question.

Comment: @tonysdg I just checked and I didn't receive any error messages. Did you notice something specific?

Comment: Nits, consider opening and validating the file is open in the caller and pass the open `FILE *` pointer (e.g `FILE *fp`) to your function instead of the filename (up to you). Consider using a static buffer to read input e.g. `#define MAXC 2048` and then `char buf[MAXC] = ""; size_t n = 0;` and control your loop with `while (n < COUNTIES_IN_SD && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { size_t len = strlen(buf); /* validate len */ countyList[n] = malloc (len + 1); strcpy (countyList[n++], buf); }` That is less susceptible to *Undefined Behavior* on files with less than `COUNTIES_IN_SD` lines of data.

Comment: I didn't see anything in particular, sorry. And I just compiled and ran your code on my own Linux box -- it appears to work, though the comparison in the for loop only captures `COUNTIES_IN_SD - 1` lines (which I doubt is what you want). Perhaps consider running your code through `valgrind`? That's a useful tool for checking for undefined behavior & memory leaks.

Comment: The problem appears to be a complete failure to validate the return of `fgets` (and `malloc`). If for any reason there is an error anywhere in reading `COUNTIES_IN_SD` worth of data, you invoke *Undefined Behavior* by attempting to store `EOF` as a `char` (it won't fit).

Comment: That fixed the problem. I implemented it in the other areas as well and everything is running smoothly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @yuankhan, glad you got it working, but don't forget the validations....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to tell where all your errors may be because you have not posted [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

That said, there are several glaring errors in your logic that invite *Undefined Behavior* on any allocation failure or any read error with `fgets` as none of your calls to `malloc` or `fgets` are validated by checking the return of either to verify your function calls succeeded.

Further, on any read failure with `fgets` the value of `countyList[iii]` will remain indeterminate as `fgets` will return `NULL` on failure, but there is no requirement that the contents of `countyList[iii]` will be set. If `EOF` is encountered before `COUNTIES_IN_SD` number of records (lines) of data are read, you invoke *Undefined Behavior* by continuing to blindly read from the file with `fgets` despite the stream error condition being set.

Instead, you can refactor your read loop to condition continuing allocation on the successful return of `fgets` while insuring you don't continue reading past `COUNTIES_IN_SD` number of items by keeping a simple counter (which I would suggest returning through a pointer passed as an additional parameter to your function)

You could do something like the following to eliminate the potential for undefined behavior by simply validating the allocations and reads. You also benefit by reading into a fixed length buffer (appropriately sized for the maximum anticipated line length), which allows you to validate the read and get the appropriate required length before allocation storage for the line, e.g.

```
#define MAXC 2048   /* size as appropriate for line length (don't skimp) */

char** fillCountyList (char *inputFile)
{
    char **countyList = NULL;
    char buf[MAXC] = "";        /* fixed buffer to validate read */
    FILE *input;
    size_t n = 0;               /* counter for no. records read */

    input = fopen (inputFile, "r");
    // checkFileOpen(input); //a separate function (we can't see it?)
    if (input == NULL) {
        perror ("fopen-fillCountyList")
        return NULL;
    }

    /* allocate COUNTIES_IN_SD pointers */
    countyList = malloc (COUNTIES_IN_SD * sizeof *countyList);
    if (!countyList) {          /* validate malloc succeeded */
        perror ("malloc-countyList");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* read up to COUNTIES_IN_SD line, validating return of fgets */
    while (n < COUNTIES_IN_SD && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
        size_t len = strlen (buf);
        if (len && buf[len-1] == '\n')
            buf[--len] = 0;     /* overwrite '\n' with '\0' */
        else if (len == MAXC - 1) {
            /* handle line to long for buf */
        }
        /* allocate len + 1 characters for countyList[n] */
        countyList[n] = malloc (len + 1);
        if (countyList[n] == NULL) {    /* validate malloc succeeded */
            perror ("malloc-countyList[n]");
            if (n)      /* if records stored, return partial list */
                break;
            else
                return NULL;    /* otherwise return NULL */
        }
        n++;
    }

    return countyList;
}
```

(adding the additional parameter to make the number of records read available back in the caller is left to you)

**Note:** you can also initialize your allocation of pointers to all zero with `calloc` (effectively initializing the pointers `NULL`) and add one more pointer to insure you always have a *sentinel* `NULL` immediately following the last allocated `countyList`, e.g.

```
    countyList = calloc (COUNTIES_IN_SD + 1, sizeof *countyList);
```

(though I would prefer to return the number successfully read through a pointer)

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.